# Find the list that best matches reference list

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to find how well several different lists match a reference list. I'm looking for a percentage or some kind of similarity score.

For example,

```
a = {"A278", "G279", "S280", "G281", "I282", "I283", "I284", "S285", 
"D286", "T287", "P288", "V289", "H290", "D291", "C292"}
b = {"S280", "G281", "I282", "I284"}
c = {"C275", "S276", "T277", "A278", "G279"}
```

How can I determine that `b` is a better match against `a` than `c`? `a` is the reference list.

Order matters.

After looking through the documentation, the only way I can think of doing this is to iterate through `b` and `c` and test if each element is `MemberQ` of `a`, tallying up the total and comparing the totals at the end. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You might consider looking through the whole bunch of `*Distance[]`/`*Dissimilarity[]` functions available. `SequenceAlignment[]` might also be of use.

Comment: Testing as described in the last paragraph of the question does not take account of order.  If order actually does not matter, consider `Complement`.

Comment: Working on `Complement` now, it seems promising @bbgodfrey

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe:

```
LongestCommonSequence[a, b]
```

> {"S280", "G281", "I282", "I284"}

```
LongestCommonSequence[a, c]
```

> {"A278", "G279"}

```
Length@LongestCommonSequence[a, #] & /@ {b, c}
```

> {4, 2}

Answer (score 9):

```
MaximalBy[Length[a⋂#]&]@{b,c}
```

> {{"S280", "G281", "I282", "I284"}}

```
MinimalBy[Length@Complement[a,#]&]@{b,c}
```

> {{"S280", "G281", "I282", "I284"}}

Comment: +1 for conciseness, this is better than my answer

Comment: @briennakh, yours is probably faster.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose I have the reference list `a` and a matrix `otherLists` of all other lists I want to compare against `a`:

```
otherLists[[Ordering[Length[#] & /@ (Complement[a, #] & /@ otherLists), 1]]]
```

This will return the list that best matches `a`.

Comment: you can use just `Length` instead of `Length[#] &`.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer @MarcoB — Write a comment.

Comment: I rolled back my changes. @kglr 's comment is suggesting the same change. Is there a reason you prefer to retain your version?

Comment: My answer works. If you want to optimize my answer, you can add your suggestion as a comment or upvote kglr's comment. Thank you. @MarcoB

Comment: @briennakh It certainly works, but the usage of `Length[#]&` where `Length` would suffice is unnecessary. This site is collaboratively edited, so I made a change that, in my opinion, improved this answer for future readers. Anyway, I will leave it as it was; perhaps you might consider making a change yourself.

Comment: I like seeing where I could improve. Otherwise we won't know why kglr made his comment. In my opinion, future readers would appreciate seeing the original answer, to know why kglr made his comment.

Answer (score 5):

Going off your percent similarity idea, maybe something like

```
listsim[ref_, test_] := {#, 100. (1 - Length@Complement[ref, #]/Length@ref)} & /@ test

listsim[a, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{{A278,G279,S280,G281,I282,I283,I284,S285,D286,T287,P288,V289,H290,D291,C292},100.}
>   {{S280,G281,I282,I284},26.6667}
>   {{C275,S276,T277,A278,G279},13.3333}}

which ended up being in a similar vein to your answer.

Comment: I like this!! Thanks!